# How To append new label after other label

Tags: javascript, html

I have one label

```
<label for="form_gpd_mail" class="form-label">Email</label>
```

But I am confused how to append that label with new label beside `form_gpd_mail` label with javascript.

please help me

Comment: Hey, can you expand on what you mean by "new label"? Is it a copy of the other? Also show us what javascript code you have already tried. People love to see what you have tried.

Comment: Do you have jQuery available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With vanilla JavaScript, this will do the trick

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-label");
var label = x[0];    
var secondLabel = document.createElement("LABEL");
secondLabel.setAttribute('id', 'secondLabel'); // Change to your desired ID
secondLabel.innerHTML = "second label"; // Change to your desired label content
x[0].parentNode.insertBefore(secondLabel, x[0].nextSibling);
```

Remember to customize your new label.

Or, if you want to put the label Inside of the other label, use `appendChild`, like

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-label");
var label = x[0];    
var secondLabel = document.createElement("LABEL");
secondLabel.setAttribute('id', 'secondLabel'); // Change to your desired ID
secondLabel.innerHTML = "second label"; // Change to your desired label content
x[0].appendChild(secondLabel, x[0].nextSibling);
```